# Is there a way to conditionally format a cells that are populated from an arrayformula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

**Background:**
I have a sheet that many people edit.  I have spent more time than I care to admit user-proofing it. (There is a list of things I have tried at the bottom of this post if you are curious).  The solution that has worked the best is letting my users "see" if a cell has a formula in it.  I have an apps script that when combined with conditional formatting highlights the cell, alerting them to please not type over it. Still, this hasn't quite solved the problem. (Especially when they insert rows.)

**Issue:**
I recently revised these sheets, replacing thousands of formulas with a handful of arrayformulas. That has fixed more problems than it's causing, but now my users get a little freaked out when they type in a cell in an arrayformula column and the whole column of data disappears.  I was hoping that there was some way to modify the isFormula app script I am using to highlight the cells that it applies to.  My thinking is this:  figure out if the formula in the cell is an arrayformula.  If true, highlight the cells that are populated by the formula.

**The script I am hoping can be altered:  isFormula():**

```
/**
 * Used to conditionally format cells having formulas
 *
 * @param {number,number} input The column number and 
          column row to start evaluating this formual and starting 
 * @return if getFormula() returns any value, false otherwise
 * @customfunction
 */
function isFormula(startcol, startrow) {
  // prepare string
  var str = String.fromCharCode(64 + startcol) + startrow;

  // retrieve formula
  var fCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getRange(str).getFormula();

  // return false if empty else true 
  return fCell ? true : false;
}
```

**The conditional formatting rule:**

`=isformula(A1)`

**Workarounds I tried:**

- **User Education:** I did try getting them to notice if there was a
  formula, and not type over it, but that approach failed. My users
  would type over the formulas, or insert rows, or accidentally move
  cells and I would be back here again.
- **Applying Permissions:**  I tried limiting permissions to cells with formulas, but that caused problems with sorting and filtering. There are hundreds of rows... they do need to be able to sort.

**A shout out to the helpers:**

- Thanks for helping! You are wonderful and amazing!

-s.

Comment: Teach them about filter views. Protect the sheets :)

Comment: There's already a ISFORMULA() built-in why do you need this script? I'd rather just teach them the undo button and what it does....